# Splitting only particular words using REGEX

Tags: java, regex

```
Vector<Object> ob = new Vector<Object>();
        Pattern p= Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]|| |(Ted)|(Barry)");
        Matcher m= p.matcher(s);

        while(m.find()){
            ob.add(m.group());
        }
```

Hi all,
I'm trying to get REGEX to split all words and numbers into seperate tokens but I want certain compound words to be split.

So with the code above my problem is that I want

`xrayTed`

to split into

`xray` and `Ted`

but it has already accepted the whole token
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is interpreted from left to right, so if regex engine in case of

```
regex1|regex2|regex3
```

will first try to find match for `regex1`, then if not succeeded with `regex2`, and lastly `regex3` (if not succeeded with `regex2`).

So in your case `xrayTed` would be matched by `[A-Za-z]+`. If you wan't to finding `Ted` or `Barry` had higher priority move it before `[A-Za-z]+` so try with

```
Pattern.compile("(Ted)|(Barry)|[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]|| ");
```

Also in your case you will have to break matching `[A-Za-z]+` if it will try to match first letter of `Ted` or `Barry`. To do so you can use [negative-look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism like `((?!Ted|Barry)[A-Za-z])+`

So try with

```
Pattern.compile("(Ted)|(Barry)|((?!Ted|Barry)[A-Za-z])+|[0-9]|| ");
```

Comment: `"(Ted)|(Barry)|([A-Za-z](?!Ted|Barry))+|[0-9]|| "`
Seems to drop the y from xrayTed for some reason?  
Looks like it stores an empty token for y so it splits it  
`xra  
    
Ted`

Comment: @RobForan Sorry, I messed up with `([A-Za-z](?!Ted|Barry))+`. It should be `((?!Ted|Barry)[A-Za-z])+` to not accept character if it is first character of `Ted` or `Barry`, not character before `Ted` or `Barry`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you:

```
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]+|[0-9])(Ted|Barry)|[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]");
Matcher m= p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    if(m.group(2) != null) {
        ob.add(m.group(1));
        ob.add(m.group(2));
    } else {
        ob.add(m.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congrats on your first answer!  Don't forget to make sure your posted code will compile (you forgot a `}`) and explain what your code does!  An answer with an explanation is much more helpful than just a code snippet  :)